# mat-menu doesn't correctly work - Angular

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I want the mat-item to be different with different mat-menus, I don't know what exactly the problem is or I misunderstood something, but all mat-menus take the values of the last mat-menu and take its mat-items.To be honest, I did not really understand how to use them and did not find a full-fledged tutorial, perhaps because of this I make a stupid mistake, so do not judge strictly.
That's my HTML:

```html
<div class="header background">
  <a mat-button><span>Sell your art</span></a>
  <a mat-button><span>Login</span></a>
  <a mat-button><span>Signup</span></a>
</div> 
 
<div class="container">
  <div class="form">
    <span><svg role="img" data-testid="ds-2019-logo" viewBox="0 0 197 40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="node_modules--redbubble-design-system-react-Logo-styles__svg--148yc"><title>Redbubble logo</title><path data-testid="ds-wordmark" fill="#333" d="m68.434 34.027-0.11764-3.2012c-0.062742-1.7555-0.19868-5.8429-0.19868-5.8429-0.078428-2.5215-0.59605-4.4024-3.1044-5.0821v-0.12026c2.1097-0.84049 3.5815-3.2025 3.5815-6.4023 0-5.0442-2.3881-7.3644-7.0062-7.3644h-7.0847v28.013h4.5371v-11.525h2.1894c1.7908 0 2.4287 1.081 2.4679 2.9607l0.16078 5.7645a123.59 123.59 0 0 1 0.0366 2.7999h4.5384zm-4.4965-18.408c-0.039214 1.6405-0.59605 3.3619-2.7463 3.3619h-2.1515v-8.8846h2.1894c2.0313 0 2.7868 1.8012 2.7476 3.3214l-0.039214 2.2012zm133.81 18.408v-4.1619h-7.2846v-8.3238h5.9318v-4.1619h-5.9318v-7.2036h7.286v-4.1619h-11.824v28.013h11.824-0.001307zm-14.461 0v-4.1619h-7.286v-23.851h-4.5384v28.013h11.824zm-20.76 0c3.3057 0 6.171-2.4012 6.171-7.963 0-3.2822-1.6313-5.5632-3.8221-6.3239v-0.15816c2.2705-0.96074 3.6639-3.2809 3.6639-6.3631 0-5.2024-2.5489-7.2036-6.4102-7.2036h-7.6833v28.013h8.0807v-0.001307zm1.2745-19.049c-0.039214 1.9999-1.3542 2.9214-2.5489 2.9214h-2.3084v-7.8036h2.23c1.911 0 2.7058 0.92022 2.6666 3.1606l-0.039214 1.7215zm0.2392 11.605c0 2.2417-0.91499 3.4025-2.9071 3.4025h-2.1894v-8.4049h2.0705c1.911 0 3.026 1.362 3.026 3.2025v1.7999zm-18.546 7.4441c3.3044 0 6.1697-2.4012 6.1697-7.963 0-3.2822-1.6313-5.5632-3.8207-6.3239v-0.15816c2.2692-0.96074 3.6626-3.2809 3.6626-6.3631 0-5.2024-2.5489-7.2036-6.4102-7.2036h-7.6833v28.013h8.082v-0.001307zm1.2745-19.049c-0.040521 1.9999-1.3542 2.9214-2.5489 2.9214h-2.3084v-7.8036h2.2287c1.911 0 2.7071 0.92022 2.6666 3.1606l-0.039214 1.7215h0.001307zm0.2379 11.605c0 2.2417-0.91499 3.4025-2.9058 3.4025h-2.1894v-8.4049h2.0692c1.911 0 3.026 1.362 3.026 3.2025v1.7999zm-19.706 7.9657c4.8168 0 6.886-3.162 6.886-7.5239v-21.011h-4.2992v20.889c0 1.762-0.43789 3.5227-2.4679 3.5227-2.1502 0-2.5489-2.0417-2.5489-3.4417v-20.97h-4.5384v21.33c0 4.8429 2.5489 7.2023 6.967 7.2023l0.001307 0.002614zm-15.607-0.52024c3.3044 0 6.171-2.4012 6.171-7.963 0-3.2822-1.6326-5.5632-3.8221-6.3239v-0.15947c2.2692-0.96074 3.6626-3.2809 3.6626-6.3631 0-5.2024-2.5489-7.2036-6.4089-7.2036h-7.6846v28.013h8.082zm1.2745-19.049c-0.039214 1.9999-1.3542 2.9214-2.5489 2.9214h-2.3084v-7.8036h2.2287c1.911 0 2.7084 0.92022 2.6679 3.1606l-0.039214 1.7215zm0.2379 11.605c0 2.2417-0.91499 3.4025-2.9058 3.4025h-2.1894v-8.4049h2.0705c1.911 0 3.0247 1.362 3.0247 3.2025v1.7999zm-19.348 7.4441c4.1397 0 6.4494-2.1607 6.4494-6.7226v-14.73c0-4.4429-2.3489-6.5631-6.5696-6.5631h-7.4441v28.013h7.5644v0.002614zm1.8705-6.9226c0 1.7607-0.55684 2.7999-2.7868 2.7999h-2.1097v-19.77h2.1502c2.2287 0 2.7868 1.3202 2.7868 2.8012l-0.039214 14.168-0.001307 0.001307zm-24.166 6.92v-28.012h11.824v4.1619h-7.286v7.2023h5.9318v4.1645h-5.9318v8.3238h7.286v4.1619h-11.824v-0.002614z"></path><path data-testid="ds-brandmark" fill="#e41321" d="m27.621 27.225h-5.3279a0.53462 0.53462 0 0 1-0.53331-0.53592v-13.372c0-0.29541 0.2392-0.53462 0.53331-0.53462h4.9397c3.707 0 4.4848 2.1829 4.4848 4.0129 0 1.0588-0.28103 1.8993-0.83918 2.5162 1.3594 0.56076 2.0914 1.8248 2.0914 3.6534 0 2.6679-1.9999 4.2599-5.3488 4.2599m-7.7356 0h-11.066a0.53331 0.53331 0 0 1-0.532-0.53592v-13.372c0-0.29541 0.2379-0.53462 0.532-0.53462h5.1697c3.2286 0 5.1553 1.7385 5.1553 4.6508 0 1.9372-0.97381 3.4587-2.5437 4.0769l3.6822 4.8246a0.53592 0.53592 0 0 1-0.39868 0.88885m0.019607-27.188c-11.037 0-19.986 8.9486-19.986 19.986 0 11.04 8.9486 19.989 19.987 19.989s19.986-8.9486 19.986-19.987-8.946-19.986-19.985-19.986"></path></svg></span>
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder=" Search designs and products" class="search left">
    </form>
    <div>
      <mat-icon class="icon">favorite_border</mat-icon>   
      <mat-icon>shopping_cart</mat-icon> 
    </div>   
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <!-- Can you explain [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" what is doing and #menu="matMenu"? -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Clothing</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All clothing</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Dresses</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Hoodies & Sweetshirts</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Leggins</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Skirts</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Socks</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <!-- Stickers -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Stickers</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All Stickers</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Car Stickers</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Helmet Stickers</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Hydro Flask Stickers</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Laptop Stickers</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Magnets</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <!-- Masks -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Masks</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All Masks</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Fitted Masks</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Flat Masks</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Kids Masks</button>
      
    </mat-menu>
    <!-- Phone cases -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Phone Cases</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All Phone Cases</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>iPhone Cases</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Samsung Cases</button>
      
    </mat-menu>
    <!-- Wall art -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Wall Art</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All Wall Art</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Art Board Prints</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Art Prints</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Canvas Prints</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Framed Prints</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Metal Prints</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <!-- Home & Living -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Home & Living</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All Home & Living</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Acrylic Blocks</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Aprons</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Bath Mats</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Clocks</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Coasters</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <!-- Kids & Babies -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Kids & Babies</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All for Kids & Babies</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Toys</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Games</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Clothes</button>
      
    </mat-menu>
    <!-- Accessories -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Accessories</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All Accessories</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Backpacks</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Drawstring Bags</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Duffle Bags</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Makeup Bags</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Pins</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <!-- Stationery -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Stationery</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All Items</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <!-- Gifts -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Gifts</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All Items</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <!-- Explore designs -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Explore designs</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>All Items</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item</button>
    </mat-menu>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

my prototype will be like Redbubble, so you can look to Redbubble as an example.

Here is the ts file, but I think there is nothing to do, it's just a copypaste of example in mat menu Angular site and I also didn't understand how it works and how we can use it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uftcS.png)

So, thank for your time and help :3

P.S: Also, if you know how to make menu dropdown on hover, tell me please ;)

Comment: Please provide a working code example as a starting point, for example an Angular project in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/). It's then way easier to help you. Read more about it https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

My answer is brief and based on guesswork because you did not provide code sample (as the comment above recommends).

`#menu="matMenu"` allows you to reference this particular menu elsewhere in the template. Most notably when you have the desired functionality that clicking a button should open this menu. And hence `[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"`.

I think that since all your menu share the same reference `#menu="matMenu"` causes the reuse of the same menu. You should name each menu distinctly, e.g. `#thisMenu="matMenu"` `#thatMenu="matMenu"` etc.

Regarding opening the menu on hover, find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301126/how-to-show-the-angular-material-drop-down-on-mouse-over/54301330) and [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-toolbar-menu-ugmijs?file=app/app.component.html) too.