# MatMenu with hover showing Button underneath opened MatMenu

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

The title might be a little confusing. I will try to explain it as good as possible.

I have a `mat-table` which I fill with data. In the last column of each row I display buttons with some simple functions like delete or edit. Since the table gets really clumsy when opened on a small screen I therefor added a `mat-menu` button.

Since Angular Material does not support the hover function as far as I know I used this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301126/how-to-show-the-angular-material-drop-down-on-mouse-over/54301330).

When one entry is shown in the table, the drop down works as wanted. As soon as there are multiple rows, the `mat-menu` in the row beneath shine through the activated `mat-menu` (see pictre).

[image]

As soon as I want to click the "Delete" or "Edit" option, the hover of the `mat-menu` on the next row gets activated.

Here is a small reproduction of the problem: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-menu-stackblitz?file=app/table-basic-example.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked the example you have provided on StackBlitz and it is evident that the `mat-menu` below the desired row get activated because simply you hovered above it. I hope I understood your quest well, because you have two ways around this:

1. Delete the `style="z-index:1050"` you have provided in `<button>` which is making the `mat-menu` transparent, or
2. Simply remove the hover feature, since you already are providing a button to be clicked.

Comment: This helped to understand the problem. My solution was to remove the `z-index` from the button and add the binding `[hasBackdrop]="false"` to the `<mat-menu>` tag.